# Redirecionar a saida padrão do HCIDUMP usando GREP para um arquivo

Tags: script, bash, shell, grep

Estou usando um shell script para fazer o HCIDUMP e usando alguns filtros para gravar em um arquivo. Com o comando a seguir, o arquivo destino fica vazio.

```
hcidump -a l2cap | grep -v -e 'CAP' -e 'HCI' > onlystringsrecieved.txt
```

Usando o mesmo comando sem redirecioanr a saida para um arquivo, funciona normal no prompt de comando LXTerminal.

```
hcidump -a l2cap | grep -v -e 'CAP' -e 'HCI'
```

Comment: tens permissão de escrita para criar o "onlystringsrecieved.txt" ? que mensagem de erro aparece?

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente a saída de seu interesse não está em *stdout* mas sim em *stderr*. Redirecione *stderr* para o *stdout* e verifique se há alguma informação no arquivo após a modificação:

```
hcidump -a l2cap 2>&1 | grep -v -e 'CAP' -e 'HCI' > onlystringsrecieved.txt
```